# Java: Problemas al hacer una calculadora básica

Tags: java

A través de Scanner quise hacer un programa que realice una operación aritmética según tu elección.

1. Suma
2. Resta
3. Multiplicación
4. División

Y te diga si esta bien o si no. Estoy teniendo un error que me preguntaba si alguien me podría contestar porque es. Escribo el código a continuación y adjunto lo que me dice el error.

Código:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Problemas{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int eleccion = 0, resultado = 0;

        System.out.println("Hola, empieza el calentamiento de matematicas. Pon 1 para practicar sumas, 
                2 para restas, 3 para multiplicaciones o 4 para divisiones");
                eleccion = in.nextInt();

        if(eleccion == 1){
            System.out.println("Perfecto!, practicaras sumas.");
            System.out.println("7 + 3 = ");
            resultado = in.nextInt();
        } if(resultado == 10){
            System.out.println("Perfecto, resultado correcto, eres muy inteligente!.");
        } if(resultado != 10){
            System.out.println("Resultado incorrecto, era 10!");


        } else if(eleccion == 2){
            System.out.println("Perfecto!, practicaras restas.");
            System.out.println("20 - 5 = ");
            resultado = in.nextInt();
        } if(resultado == 15){
            System.out.println("Perfecto, resultado correcto, eres muy inteligente!.");
        } if(resultado != 15){
            System.out.println("Resultado incorrecto, era 15!");


        } else if(eleccion == 3){
            System.out.println("Perfecto!, practicaras multiplicaciones");
            System.out.println("6 x 3 = ");
            resultado = in.nextInt();
        } if(resultado == 18){
            System.out.println("Perfecto, resultado correcto, eres muy inteligente!.");
        } if(resultado != 18){
            System.out.println("Resultado incorrecto, era 18!");



        } else if(eleccion == 4){
            System.out.println("Perfecto!, practicaras divisiones.");
            System.out.println("25 : 5 = ");
            resultado = in.nextInt();
        } if(resultado  == 5){
            System.out.println("Perfecto, resultado correcto, eres muy inteligente!.");
        } if(resultado != 5){
            System.out.println("Resultado incorrecto, era 5!");
        }

    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Indenta tu código y -probablemente- lo verás.

Comment: Tus if no están bien  anidados. Te recomiendo que utilices switch(resultado) case 1: (bloque 1) break: case 2: (bloque 2) break y así para los demás. Aparte que se ve más ordenado y no te pierdes en tantos if.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer tu problema esta en la forma en la que estructuras tu código. Los mensajes de resultado incorrecto se muestran debido a que haces la comprobación fuera de los `if` y en  consecuencia, el programa sigue ejecutándose.

Podrías mejorar tu código reemplazando los `if` por  `switch case`, no obstante, si decides seguir con los `if`, entonces, debes organizarlos de forma parecida a ésta:

```
    if(eleccion == 1){
        System.out.println("Perfecto!, practicaras sumas.");
        System.out.println("7 + 3 = ");
        resultado = in.nextInt();

        if(resultado == 10){
            System.out.println("Perfecto, resultado correcto, eres muy inteligente!.");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Resultado incorrecto, era 10!");
        }
   }
```

Utilizando el `if` anidado la comprobación se ejecutará solo si el valor es 1, o el que desees. Es recomendable cambiar el `if(resultado != 10)` por un `else` que se ejecuta de manera automática si la condición  de su `if` no se cumple.